# How to mock non static logger with PowerMock?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito, powermockrunner

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Service {
    private final Logger lgr = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);

    public void doService() {
        lgr.info("Do Service");
    }
}

public class Controller {
    private final Logger lgr = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    protected void doSomething() {
        //do something
        lgr.info("LOG something"); // lgr line
        // do something else

    }
}
```

And the corresponding test class that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ControllerTest.class, LoggerFactory.class})
public class ControllerTest {
    private Controller controller;

    @Mock
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        controller = Mockito.mock(Controller.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {
        controller.doSomething();  // calling doSomething method of Controller class
        // some other statements
    }
}
```

Here, when the call goes to doSomething() method, at line **lgr line**, the lgr object is null, due to which my unit test is failing with NullPointerException.

Can someone please, help me fix this?

Comment: Make it static and do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948916/mocking-logger-and-loggerfactory-with-powermock-and-mockito

Comment: I know that after making the logger static, I can use mockstatic etc., but the existing class already has a on static logger class, so I prefer to not change it.

Comment: Ok, but then why are you trying to add another logger? Seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: I'm not trying to add any logger, there's an existing class which has a non static logger, and a non static method which logs something with this logger object. I'm trying to write a UT to test something in this method, but that's giving a NPE, as the lgr object in that method is null.

Comment: Are you trying to test if the logger is called? 
Or are you testing the controller.doSomething()?

if it's the latter, don't mock it but create a new instance:
 @Before
    public void init() {
        controller = new Controller()
    }

Comment: I'm mocking it, as there're a lot of autowired fields in the Controller class, which I thought would be hard to inject without adding @Mock fields.

Comment: You never Mock the class you are testing, you only mock the dependencies. :-) 

For future questions: Please share the entire class (you only shared a part, which made it difficult to see what you wanted to do).
If you update this question with your full class, i'll have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for adding. For what you want to do, you don't actually need PowerMock :-).

Here is what you should change:
- Don't put autowired on a field. Create a constructor where you pass in the Service and (optionally) put Autowired on the constructor.

- in your test Before, create a new controller and pass the Mocked Service into the constructor.

   Before
    public void init() {
        controller = new Controller(service);
    }

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way, I can programatically inject mock Service object into mock Controller object?

Comment: Through the Constructor, or by using MockitoAnnoations.initMocks() (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263208/why-cant-i-use-injectmocks-field-matching-when-running-with-powermockrunner)